# Elastic search GET method not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created index of name `gizmoindex` with type as `Employee` which contain different documents , each one has automatic generated ID. but when I am executing this query.
   For Example : -

```
localhost:9200/gizmoindex/Employee/_search
    GET
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "firstname": "gaurav"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it is not giving any output.
But If I created a user defined index like : -

```
"localhost:9200/gizmoindex/Employee/1"
```

using PUT, the above mentioned query for retreiving the result is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [URI search](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-uri-request.html) and modified your search query as below

```
curl -H GET localhost:9200/gizmoindex/Employee/_search?pretty=1 -d ' 
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "firstname": "gaurav"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```